# How to get Month from ISO Date and Week

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I'm looking for a way to convert an ISO date to Month and I also need to covert an ISO week to Month.
I need to do this in Excel and Access.
I found this formula for excel but when converting it to Access it does not work.  Is there a simple way to accomplish this?
I found this Excel formula to convert ISO date to month `(C2=date)` and it works perfect:

```
=MONTH(DATE(YEAR(C2),MONTH(C2)+(WEEKDAY(C2,2)+(DAY(DATE(YEAR(C2),MONTH(C2)+1,0)))-(DAY(C2))<4),(((7-(WEEKDAY(C2,2)))+(DAY(C2)))>3)))
```

But when I modify it for an Access query it does not return the correct values:

```
Date_to_Month:MONTH(DATESERIAL(YEAR([WW_Index].[ISO_date]),MONTH([WW_Index].[ISO_date])+(WEEKDAY([WW_Index].[ISO_date],2)+(DAY(DATESERIAL(YEAR([WW_Index].[ISO_date]),MONTH([WW_Index].[ISO_date])+1,0)))-(DAY([WW_Index].[ISO_date]))<4),(((7-(WEEKDAY([WW_Index].[ISO_date],2)))+(DAY([WW_Index].[ISO_date])))>3)))
```

---

I also need to convert ISO week_year to Month.  I found this formula but it does not work:

```
=MONTH(DATE(YEAR(C2),1,-2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(C2),1,3))+D2*7)
```

Example: week 18, 2012 is the ISO week of Apr 30 through May 6, 2012.  There is less that 4 April days in this week thus week 18, 2012 is in May.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `D2`? Functions you are using assume `C2` as a correct date. Problem must be in your formula. `=MONTH(C2)` and `=WEEKDAY(C2, 2)` return what you need!

Comment: could you settle for a sql solution ? Which SQL are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know access but you can do the first part (date to month) much more easily in excel with this formula

`=MONTH(C2-WEEKDAY(C2-1)+4)`

That should be easier to convert for access......

For the second part you are finding the **Monday** of the relevant week, hence you get the wrong month in some cases, the **Thursday** of the week (midpoint) should always be within the correct month so you can just add 3 to get that (-2 becomes 1), i.e.

`=MONTH(DATE(YEAR(C2),1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(C2),1,3))+D2*7)`

I assume C2 is a **date** within the relevant year and D2 is the ISO week number
 but probably better to have C2 containing the year, e.g. just 2013 and then you can use

`=MONTH(DATE(C2,1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(C2,1,3))+D2*7)`

Comment: Awesome!!! Thank you, Barry.  Your formulas work great and is much easier to implement.   After converting your formulas to work in an MS-Access query, it now works!